# Получить фотограцию случайного места из Google Maps

Tags: python, python-3.x, api, google-maps-api

Всем привет! ПОдскажите пожалуйста, есть ли способ получить фотограцию случайного места (например по координатам) из Google Maps не используя их собственный API? Возможно для Python есть неофициальные API Google Maps? Быстрый поиск по гитхабу результатов не дал

Comment: Знаете игру [geoguessr](https://www.geoguessr.com/)? Так вот, они используют API, платный. Если бы был бесплатный способ, думаю они им обязательно воспользовались бы.

Comment: https://randomstreetview.com/

Comment: @СергейКох сайт крутой, но там 3D вью, мне же нужны фотки загруженные людьми для этой локации. просто даже сделать скриншот с вью не подойдет(